# SharePoint 2013 custom workflow activities dll reference error on publish

Tags: workflow, workflow-activity

I have created a custom workflow activity and it is coming fine in the designer.

As soon as I publish my workflow, I get below error

(0, 10) The type or namespace name '

For this, where do I need to add my DLL's so that they are accessible?

I have added the web.config entry which is there at "**C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\CONFIG**". Tried adding it before and after TargetFx but no help.

Answer (score 0):

Try deploying the Activity dll to GAC.

To use custom activity in Workflow, you need to deploy the activity to the GAC.

Comment: I tried doing so but dgrag drop to GAC is not working

Comment: Use Gacutil.exe http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkkx7f79(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: it was of no help. still looking into it

Comment: Do you have permissions to add the assembly to the GAC?

Comment: yes i do have permission

Comment: Refering to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd587352%28v=office.11%29.aspx, in which of the web.config do i need to add safecontrol entries?

Comment: Did you add assembly to GAC?

Comment: can you PLEASE have a look at http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116339/custom-workflow-activities-in-sharepoint-2013-for-2010-workflows. maybe I was going in the wrong direction

Answer (score 0):

Deploy the Activity dll to GAC and restart visual studio. Restart is important, othervise it's not working.